# get all subsets of a specific set iteratively

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary

I know the iterative solution:

given a set of `n` elements

save an `int v = 2^n`  and generate all binaries number up to this `v`.

But what if n > 32?

I know it's already 2^32 subsets, but yet - what's the way to bypass the 32 elements limitation?

Comment: What about making an array of ints, and manually propagating the carry bit to one int to the next one? Like `[0000][1111] -> [0001][0000]` BTW, wouldn't it be terribly/impossibly slow?

Comment: Use `long` to go up to n=64. If n > 64, then it will take your program several centuries to enumerate all the subsets, so you should look for a solution to the original problem that doesn't involve enumerating subsets.

Comment: why in the world would you want to do this?  that's like one very long for loop... is this an xy problem?

Comment: I'd do exactly whit biziclop suggests. You're probably aware of the exponential runtime of that approach so you're probably not interested in actually running the enumeration, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're happy with a 64 item limit, you can simply use `long`.
2. Array / `ArrayList` of `int`s / `long`s. Have a `next` function something like:

   ```
   bool next(uint[] arr)
     for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
       if (arr[i] == 2^n-1) // 11111 -> 00000
         arr[i] = 0
       else
         arr[i]++
         return true
     return false // reached the end -> there is no next
   ```
3. [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). Probably not a very efficient option compared to the above.

   You can have a `next` function which sets the least significant bit 0 to 1 and all remaining bits to 0. e.g.:

   ```
   10010 -> 10011
   10011 -> 10100
   ```

Note - this will probably take forever, simply because there's so many subsets, but that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @biziclop approach, by propagating the carry bit in the following way: store your number as vector of 32-bit "digits" of length K. So, you can generate 2^(K*32) subsets, and every increment operation will take at most O(K) operations.
The other thing that I can think of is recursive backtrack, that will generate all subsets in one array.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an analog of this concise Haskell implementation:

```
powerSet = filterM (const [True, False])
```

Except there is no built-in `filterM` in C#. That's no problem, you can implement it yourself.
Here is my attempt at it:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PowerSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> els)
{
    return FilterM(_ => new[] {true, false}, els);
}

public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FilterM<T>(
    Func<T, IEnumerable<bool>> p,
    IEnumerable<T> els)
{
    var en = els.GetEnumerator();
    if (!en.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        yield break;
    }

    T el = en.Current;
    IEnumerable<T> tail = els.Skip(1);
    foreach (var x in
        from flg in p(el)
        from ys in FilterM(p, tail)
        select flg ? new[] { el }.Concat(ys) : ys)
    {
        yield return x;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
foreach (IEnumerable<int> subset in PowerSet(new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", string.Join(",", subset));
}
```

As you can see, neither `int` nor `long` are explicitly used anywhere in the implementation, so the real limit here is the maximum recursion depth reachable with the current stack size limit.

**UPD:** [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#C.23) gives a non-recursive implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
{
    var seed = new List<IEnumerable<T>>() { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }
        as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>;

    return input.Aggregate(seed, (a, b) =>
        a.Concat(a.Select(x => x.Concat(new List<T> { b }))));
}
```